# SourceTree Custom Actions. $SHA

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I spent last half an our searching for an explanation but I cant find it.

In Source-tree in the Custom Actions there is a option to pass $FILE, $REPO, $SHA, as I understand from the explanation in the dialog, I can use more $SHA's but I always get only one.

Is just a typo and I spent a good question on it or I just cant use it.

Example of my action.

[image]

I would like to inject more $SHA's in the command.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have verified that you can use the $REPO, $FILE and $SHA 'macros' as many times as you like.

My initial guess was that Sourcetree was getting confused by the Powershell `$(`, but I have tested it and this works perfectly:

`-Command git archive -o update.zip $SHA $(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $SHA)`

The difference between mine and yours is I have removed the trailing `..` after both instances of `$SHA`. These are invalid.

Tested in Sourcetree 2.0.14.1